# files list file for package 'gucharmap' is missing final newline

Tags: debian, apt

My OS is debian SID and i can't apt-get install anything because I am greeted with this message everytime:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package 'gucharmap' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: What version of Debian? And what version of `gucharmap`. Have you tried http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1319791? Though for safety's sake I would recommend modifying it to only print the relevant files, not alter them.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Linux Mint 17.3 when using the Update GUI.

I fixed the issue by deleting the package.list file and reinstalling the package.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/gucharmap.list 
sudo apt-get install gucharmap --reinstall
```

While this did fix my problem, I'm not sure if it could have unintended side-effects. If anyone knows of any, please post in comments :)

Answer (score 0):

SO I followed this guide here: https://blog.bartbania.com/raspberry_pi/files-list-file-missing-final-newline/

And managed to fix my problem.